# Comparing two cell values with a range of values in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have been seeking out for a solution for a problem. I have tried a couple of formulas like VLOOKUP, INDEX.. MATCH and nothing seemed to be working.
I have two range values as like below

```
Date    Rate of Interest        Date    Charge code Interest Rate
1/2/2014    1.1     5/27/2015   INTEREST     
3/20/2014   1.2     5/10/2015   INTEREST     
5/20/2014   1.3     4/12/2015   QUARTERLY AUDIT FEE  
10/20/2014  1.3     3/30/2015   LEGAL FEE    
1/10/2015   1.4     2/20/2015   COLLECTION   
6/13/2015   1.5     1/10/2015   COLLECTION   
11/20/2015  1.6     12/20/2014  COLLECTION   
12/20/2015  1.7     8/20/2014   COLLECTION   
12/21/2015  1.8     7/11/2014   INTEREST     
12/22/2015  1.9     6/30/2014   INTEREST     
12/22/2015  2       5/4/2014    COLLECTION   
12/23/2015  2.1     4/12/2014   COLLECTION   
12/24/2015  2.2     4/12/2014   COLLECTION   
12/25/2015  2.3     3/20/2014   COLLECTION   
12/26/2015  2.4     2/10/2014   COLLECTION   
12/27/2015  2.5     1/2/2014    COLLECTION   
12/30/2015  2.6     1/2/2014    ADVANCE
```

I need to compare the second range value with the first one and get the Interest Rate column filled for the second range from the first one.
Here is the business rule. The first date cell value in the second range would be compared with the list of date values in the first and if the date cell value is less than or equal to any of the date list values in the first range, and the corresponding charge code value is “INTEREST” for the date cell value in the second range, the Rate of Interest column value in the first range needs to be gotten populated in the Interest Rate column of the second range.

Any formula or VBA code would help greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming were using Columns A to E starting at row 2 for your data with a 10 rows, these are some possible solutions.

**Solution 1: Using extra column for calculation. Will work even if your DATES in first range is not sorted.**

In Column E (2nd Range Interest Rate)

```
=IF(D2="INTEREST",VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$B$10,2),"")
```

In Column F (extra column for calculation purposes)

```
=MIN(IF(C2<$A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,""))
```

*NOTE: The second formula is an array formula so PRESS CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after copying to formula bar or it wont work.*

---

**Solution 2: (If you dont want to use an extra column). Will work with your example as the DATES in first range is sorted in ascending order.**

copy this formula into the formula bar in column E (Interest Rate), but instead of pressing ENTER, press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER as this is an array formula. you need to do that everytime you change the formula.

```
=IF(D2="INTEREST",INDIRECT("B"&MIN(IF(C2<=$A$2:$A$10,ROW($A$2:$A$10),""))),"")
```

NOTE: this assumes your Dates in column A are sorted in ascending order as per your example.

---

**Solution 3: will only work if you change the sorting order of your dates in descending. But the formula is simplest.**

If you can sort your FIRST RANGE in descending DATE order instead of ascending, the formula will be alot simpler with INDEX and MATCH.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(C2,$A$2:$A$10,-1))
```

let me know if you ran into any problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Have tried your formula, but that couldn't help. I need to check C2<= with A2:A18 and D2="INTEREST". Also need to get the B2 value with the above condition. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: my bad.. i miss that little detail. updated my answer.

Comment: It is wonderful. I'm afraid, please see, if c2 <= any one of the values in a2:a10 and d2 = 'INTEREST', then I need to populate the corresponding column B value (the next cell value in the range which is matching the criteria) not the column B value where a cell (column C) is being compared. Thank you for your efforts. Hope you'd help me out with this as well.

Comment: c2<=a2:10 will have multiple match. which one is chosen then? the one closest to the date in c2? Were having a communication breakdown here.. just show me by example in your spreadsheet above. how would that spreadsheet look like once it's done.

Comment: The first matching value would be considered. expected result
5/27/2015 INTEREST 1.5
5/10/2015 INTEREST 1.5
7/11/2014 INTEREST 1.3
6/30/2014 INTEREST 1.3